# asp.net mvc 4, how to check if included table is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My controller linq code is

```
var PM = db.LTR_PropMaster
    .Include(P => P.LTR_PropPhotos)
    .Where(
        d => d.LTR_CityMaster.CityName.Contains(PL)
        && d.LTR_PropCategories.PropCatName == PT
     );
```

if include table **LTR_PropPhotos** is null, its giving error, how to check it LTR_PropPhotos have no related to that item.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by the *table* being null?

Comment: Have you tried `if(db.LTR_PropMaster == null){...}`?

Comment: Is this line causing an error, or is another part of your program causing the error. Try to point out the exact line that is failing and include the error message as well.